# android maps v2 marker scale animation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation

If you see the google maps app(the out of box app) and say you search for something like 'food', you will wither see a couple of markers as parker pins or as dots. When you tap on a dot, the dot animates and becomes a full marker pin(you can see the marker scaling up.
I was wondering if we can do the same using goole maps for android v2.

Any tips would be helpful.

ps: my current idea is to use an interpolator and replace the marker icon using setIcon couple of time, but seriously, if Google has already done it then we should be able to do it.

thanks

Comment: have you seen that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#video_animating_markers ?

Comment: not trying to be rude, but did you really understood my question? i have seen this video before and if i am not wrong they are only changing the position and i just want to scale the marker icon inplace.

Comment: so if they dont talk about any other types of animation then it most likely means that there are not any ones, otherwise they would mention it

Comment: if you see MaciejGórski's reply, he agrees that the only way to do scale animation on a marker is to set the icon every couple of seconds (or create an image view at the exact location). Anyhow, if you think you have a non-choppy solution then please do share it. I would love to see it and will accept it as answer.

Comment: no i dont have the smooth solution simply because you cannot do it using public maps v2 api

Answer (score 2):

I created a little proof of concept according to @MaciejGórski's idea.

The interesting part is [here](https://github.com/meierjan/MarkerScaleAnimationTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/wtf/meier/markeranimation/MapsActivity.kt)

```
override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
    val marker = p0!!

    val mapIcon = marker.tag as Bitmap


    val animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1F, ICON_SELECTED_SCALE_FACTOR)
    animation.duration = 600
    animation.interpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator()

    animation.addUpdateListener { animationState ->
        val scaleFactor = animationState.animatedValue as Float
        val newBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                mapIcon,
                (ICON_WIDTH * scaleFactor).toInt(),
                (ICON_HEIGHT * scaleFactor).toInt(),
                false
        )
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(newBitMap))
    }
    animation.start()

    this.animation = animation

    return true
}
```

Full example here:
https://github.com/meierjan/MarkerScaleAnimationTest

Comment: what exactly do you need?

Comment: the above code is in kotlin , please i need java code

Answer (score 1):

You current idea, i.e. replacing icon using `setIcon` every couple of milliseconds it the only way you can do that using api.

Note: every call to the api does IPC via Binders, so it may not look good. If you want the animation to look much better (more fps), I suggest putting `ImageView` on the same spot and animate it instead. After the animation finishes, just `setIcon` once.

Comment: honestly this is frustrating. google maps for iOS has those features(you can get a view associated with a marker and then perform animation on it). The stndalone Google Maps app for android works(as mentioned in the question), which makes many people wonder why i(the developer) can't simply do the same thing :(

Comment: @MaciejGorski Can you please tell me how to create ImageView on the same spot?